# Image Trace vs. Create Outlines

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm creating a logo from text in Adobe Illustrator. I know I have to convert the text to an image before saving it. Which tool would be better for this, image trace or create outlines?

Comment: Image trace doesn't work on a text object.

Comment: Hi Michelle, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I'm confused by your question, why do you need to convert the text to an image before saving?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Convert Text to Outlines" is your best option. It is a direct conversion to vector format using the font's own metrics. Image trace is not only not available for text, but even if you could use it, it would be far less accurate. Image trace is more of a time saving tool to quickly convert raster image data to editable vectors. It is an excellent tool, but it's the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Agree with 13ruce completely. Image Trace can also warp the design curves/points, and you probably want those precise for a logo design. Definitely go with "Convert Text to Outlines"